# com.bleplx.BlePlxModule.state (BlePlxModule.java:2)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ble-plx

App is crashing some time when i am launching the Android app.

> React native: 71.6 Ble-plx: I have updated the version to
> recent(3.1.2)

I am getting below error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String n4.b.y()' on a null object reference
```

Complete log:

```
com.bleplx.BlePlxModule.state (BlePlxModule.java:2)  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)  
com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:148)  
com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:147)  
com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run (SourceFile)  
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:958)
```

I have updated the react-native version. But still getting the same error.